Surface held in place by a force?
Assume $n=3$. Consider a codimension one constant positive Gaussian curvature surface of revolution $S$ and an embedding $e:S \hookrightarrow X^n$ for $X^n=[0,1]^n$ with points $p,q$ elements of $\partial X^n$ where $\partial X^n=X^n-(0,1)^n$ for $\mathrm {sup}~ \mathrm{dist}(p,q)=\sqrt{n}$. Delete $p,q$ from $S$ which doesn't change $\mathrm{Vol}(S)$ nor $K$ (Gaussian curvature).
We know $K$ is invariant under isometries of $S$, but we cannot pullback by an isometry to get a cylinder, which has zero Gaussian curvature, because this would violate the notion of isometry (besides the point, it is true that there exists a diffeomorphism taking $S$ to an open cylinder). Note that positive constant Gaussian curvature surfaces of revolution $S$ exist in this context. So, in a sense, deleting $p,q$ from $S$ keeps the surface tethered to those now missing points.

Is there a way to mathematically describe the surface accumulating to $p,q$ as a force - perhaps $p,q$ are attractive forces keeping $S$ from being pulled back further by isometry?

My attempt: Deleting points $ p $ and $ q $ from a surface $S'=S\setminus \lbrace p,q \rbrace$ of constant Gaussian curvature introduces singularities. I've mathematically modeled the situation with the energy functional:
$$
\mathcal{E}(S') = \int_{S'} H^2 \, dA + \lambda \left( \int_{S'} \frac{1}{d(x, p)^\alpha} \, dA + \int_{S'} \frac{1}{d(x, q)^\alpha} \, dA \right).
$$
Where $ H $ is the mean curvature and $ dA $ is the area element on the surface and $\lambda>0$ is a constant. The first integral is related to the Willmore energy.
To describe this tethering mathematically, we introduce a potential function $ V(x)$ that models attractive forces acting near $ p $ and $ q$. Let $ d(x, p) $ denote the geodesic distance between a point $ x \in S $ and $ p $, and define the potential as:
$$
V(x) = \frac{1}{d(x, p)^\alpha} + \frac{1}{d(x, q)^\alpha},
$$
where $ \alpha > 0 $ controls the strength of the potential near the deleted points.
The corresponding force field $F(x)$ is the negative gradient of the potential $V(x)$ on the surface $ S $, which can be written as:
$$
F(x) = - \nabla_S V(x),
$$
where $ \nabla_S $ is the gradient operator with respect to the Riemannian metric $ g $ on the surface $ S $. Explicitly, this gives:
$$
F(x) = -\alpha \left( \frac{\nabla_S d(x, p)}{d(x, p)^{\alpha+1}} + \frac{\nabla_S d(x, q)}{d(x, q)^{\alpha+1}} \right).
$$
This force field acts to "pull" the surface towards the deleted points $ p $ and $ q $, with the strength of the force increasing as $ x \to p $ or $ x \to q $.
